# Highlight words in document using office.js for Word 2013

Tags: ms-word, office-js

There is a list of words that needs to be highlighted in the word document, how can the words be highlighted from the add-in when using office.js (common APIs) for Word 2013?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straightforward way to do this with Office.js in Word 2013.

With Word 2016 you can use [WordApi](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-reference-overview) to [search](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body?product=word?product=word#searchsearchtext-string-searchoptions-searchoptions) for content and [format](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range?product=word?product=word) the results. These APIs are not applicable to Word 2013 however.

For Word 2013, would need to extract the raw OOXML, manipulate it externally yourself and then replace the OOXML in the document. Since the user would need to first ""select all", this isn't a very practical solution.